# Error: @babel/helper-plugin-utils/src/index.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (93:5) while trying to build application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs

While i'am trying to run "npm run build":

```
    "start": "npm run build && node ./dist/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node ./index.js",
    "debug": "node --inspect-brk ./dist/index.js",
    "clean": "rm -rf build && mkdir build",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run build-babel ",
    "build-babel": "babel src --out-dir ./dist --source-maps --ignore 'node_modules/**/*.js'",
    "build-client": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
```

I am getting error:

```
{ SyntaxError: /home/marcin/Pobrane/recipeapp-style/src/client/node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/src/index.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (93:5)

  91 |       version,
  92 |       range,
> 93 |     }: any),
     |      ^
  94 |   );
  95 | }
```

I've had nodejs project and nested project created in reactjs (CRA) in my project in "client" folder.

I've tried this - https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8944
But it doesn't help me.

My folder structure looks like this

- build
- dist
- node_modules
- src

  - client (here is create-react-app)
  - ....many less significant folders
- .babelrc
- index.js
- package-lock.json
- package.json

If you think this is something else, please let me know.

I would like to build my project an hosted it on heroku, but i have to build it using babel (because ES6).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I realised that in my client module I have package.json file that is totally making babel freak out and lose its configuration from `.babelrc`. Adding `.babelrc` to that package won't help.

I would recommend you to remove package.json file from client app. Also remove node_modules from client too as babel will accidentially try to compile them too.

Of course remember to set correct presets in `.babelrc`.

Mine are:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react", // JSX
    "@babel/preset-flow" // static typing
  ]
}
```

I have no idea why is it happening this way.

Cheers.